# How to pass shell variables into a PHP function call as arguments?

Tags: php, shell, command-line-interface

I'm calling a PHP script from command line:

```
/usr/bin/php -r "require '/path/to/php/dummy.php'; echo getFunction(\"DummyParameter\")";
```

The call works like a charm, and the PHP function returns the correct value. I want to replace `DummyParameter` with a `$ShellVariable`. When I replace `DummyParameter`, it is supposed to be passed as `"$ShellVariable"` string. Here is what I have tried:

```
/usr/bin/php -r "require '/path/to/php/dummy.php'; echo getFunction(\"$ShellVariable\")";
```

Is there any way to pass the shell variable into the PHP script as a function argument?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably can—but getting proper escaping will possibly be very difficult to get right and will require rather messy code. Is it a proof of concept? Because it's trivial if you just write the code in a file.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the CLI arguments and use the [`$argv`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) array, e.g.:

```
php -r 'printf("%s\n", $argv[1]);' "$(date)"
```

*Sample Output*

```
Tue Nov 29 14:09:07 +07 2016
```